Equivalent Thevenin resistance

Do you know any applications that can solve the Thevenin resistance of this circuit?

Purely by visual inspection it can be seen that no current flows through R2, R3 and R4 when a voltage is applied to the Thevenin terminals. This is your major route to a solution and I'll leave the rest to you: -
Hint: no current flows through R2, R3 and R4 because the voltage across that limb is zero due to other resistors being symmetrical in value. That means you can remove that limb or short it out and seriously simplify your circuit. Removed: -

Really easy after this.
